# Perform search on instance object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code:

```
  @anatomy = Anatomy.find_by_sql(" some long sql here")
```

I want to perform a search on the @anatomy resultset.

I tried the code below but it does not seem to work.

```
@anatomy_subset = @anatomy.find :first, :conditions => ["public_id = ?", public_id ]
```

It is giving me:

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

How do I search for something on the @anatomy instance object?

Thank a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make SQL search out of SQL server, do this instead:

```
subset = @anatomy.select { |entity| entity.public_id == public_id }
```